# M table using a predefined type per column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

In the following M query:

```
let
    #"My Source" = Table.FromRecords({
        [Name="Jared Smith", Age=24],
        [Name = "Tom Brady", Age=44],
        [Name="Hello Tom", Age = null],
        [Name = "asdf", Age = "abc"]
    })
in
    #"My Source"
```

Why does "abc" not produce an error? Does PowerPivot use the "any" type unless the type is explicitly defined?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Although in certain circumstances, such as when you get the data from an Excel Table, it will automatically detect the data type depending on whether all of the entries in the column are of the same type.  Sometimes it does this incorrectly -- eg always converting Date to Date/Time, when you might really want just Date. You can also write your own functions to detect and assign data types.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how would you set the type when importing from records? Or do you need to explicitly cast in the next step, with `Table.TransformColumnTypes` ?

Comment: You need to explicitly cast it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld -- thanks, would you want to add an answer showing that and I can accept that?

Comment: Thanks. I will do that in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the type for each column using the `#table` function:

```
let
    Source = #table(
        type table
            [
                #"Name"=text,
                #"Age"=number
            ], 
            {
                {"Jared Smith", 24},
                {"Tom Brady", 4},
                {"Hello Tom", null},
                {"asdf", "abc"}
            }
        )
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comments: Power Query does use the ANY data type unless you specifically assign one.

in certain circumstances, such as when you get the data from an Excel Table, it will automatically detect the data type depending on whether all of the entries in the column are of the same type. Sometimes it does this incorrectly -- eg always converting Date to Date/Time, when you might really want just Date.

You can use `Table.TransformColumnTypes` to do this.  You can even write your own routine to detect and assign data types.

You will note that if you change the `DataType` of your `Age` column to `Whole Number`, the `abc` cell will show `Error`

You can also write routines to handle the mixed data type in the single column by, for example, splitting them out to their own columns.